# Limit of difference of sequences

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$, $(b_n)_{n\geq 1}$ e $(c_n)_{n\geq 1}$ sequences of positive real numbers such that $c_n\nearrow +\infty$ and $(a_n-b_n)/c_n\to 0$,
as $n \nearrow +\infty$; and $(b_n/c_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is bounded. Is this enough to ensure the existence of

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{b_n}{c_n}?$$

Answer (score 2):

No, your conditions are not sufficient to guarantee the existence of the limit. For example, have $a_n = b_n = n + 1 + n\cos(n\pi)$ and $c_n = n$. Then $c_n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$. Also, $\frac{a_n - b_n}{c_n} = 0$, so its limit is obviously $0$ as $n \to \infty$. In addition, $\frac{b_n}{c_n} = 1 + \frac{1}{n} + \cos(n\pi)$ is bounded by $0$ below and $3$ above. However,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{b_n}{c_n} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n} + \cos(n\pi)\right) \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

The first limit is useless since we can take $a_n=b_n$. You are asking if $\frac {b_n} {c_n}$ converges whenever it is bounded and $c_n$ increases to $\infty$. For a counterexample take $b_n=n$ for $n$ even, $2n$ for $n$ odd and take $c_n=n$ for all $n$.